# Short story: man & woman driving out of town, raining forever, woman leaving man for the petrol station guy

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, episode-identification

I can't remember the title, nor any exact parts of the text, also it was quite a poor story but it somehow seemed to respond to Ward Moore's "Lot" which is one of my favorites.  I've read this other version in *Galaktika Magazin* (Hungarian) but lost the paper version so now I'm looking for it. It was the relaunched, A5 sized version, way after 2004.

The couple traveled in a car, driving towards the mountains because it was raining and somehow they knew it was going to rain forever; something like Genesis flood, can't remember exactly.  But then they stopped at a gas station and the woman thought it all over and stayed with the station operator instead of going back to the car.  She was very happy with her decision - just as Mr Jimmon in the original story.

So, anyone heard of such?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction and Fantasy SE. Take a look at [this](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) guide to help jog your memory and edit any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where?

Comment: There was a sequel; [Lot's Daughter](http://english.netmassimo.com/2015/05/14/lots-daughter-by-ward-moore/) could that be it?

Comment: @Valorum - no, definitely not.  There was no direct connection between Lot and this one; it just "felt like", and compared to Lot the scene was turned around. (Annoying husband, smart wife with logical thinking, etc) It was nothing significant, not even close to Ward Moore. Oh and a female author, but you might have guessed already :)

Comment: That should make it easier. Fewer volumes to look through. Though probably fewer people who read it too.

Comment: Yup... But I couldn't find a complete list of the stories in them.  Do you know any?

Comment: Was it possibly *Rings of Ice* by Piers Anthony?

Comment: @Mithrandir - not remotely, Mr Gandalf :) That one's a book while this is a short story.

Comment: What the heck, they're publishing the new *Galaktika* every month, so now there's over a hundred issues?  I was wrong, it won't be easier.  You can find all of them in FSzEK, but it might take you days to find the right story if you don't recognize it from the table of contents.

Comment: @b_jonas - good tip, I'll give it a try, thank you.  I might as well recognize it by title; I can probably exclude a lot anyway.  Upvoted!